# Green Functions of Heat and Wave Equations for both Drichlet and Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

**Definition of Drichlet Boundary Conditions:**

If we have a PDE and we have some boundary conditions as: $$y(0)=y_0, y^{'}(0)=y_1$$ and $$y(a)=y_a, y(b)=y_b$$
these types of conditions. Then at boundary conditions simple values exist.

**Definition of Neumann Boundary Conditions:**

In 2 dimension, at boundary conditions we have tangents and they are boundary conditions. Then at boundary conditions differential values exist.

$$u_x(x, y, t)=g(x, y, t), \forall (x, y)$$

**Definition of Heat Equation:**

$$u_t-ku_{xx}=0, 0 \leq x \leq L, t \geq 0$$

$$u(0, t)=u(L, t)=0, t \geq 0$$
$$u(x, 0)=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq L$$

These are Drichlet BCs.

**Definition of Wave Equation:**

$$u_{tt}=c^{2}(u_{xx}+u_{tt})+Q(x, t)$$

$$u(x, 0)=f(x)$$
$$u_t(x, 0)=g(x)$$

How to find Green Functions of Heat and Wave Equations for both Drichlet and Neumann BCs. Pls if possible show all steps. In text book it is too rigorous to understand. Would appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: In the first case are you working on ODE? And is $0 = a, b$?

Comment: I am not working on ODE. I have just provided definitions to be used while solving for Green Functions

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what are you trying to ask? I just want to know how to find Green Functions of Heat and Wave Equations for both Drichlet and Neumann BCs that's why I have mentioned basic definitions.

Comment: In your definition of dirichlet boundary condition, can you specify where is your PDE defined?

Comment: This question is too broad. To start with, you might try searching Google for "Greens function wave equation"...  then asking a question about any specifics you get stuck on

Comment: PDE is defined of Heat Equation.